# Google Map component can be dragged from outside card it's in and zoom control moves

Tags: css, reactjs

### Found my own solution. See answer below the original post.

I've made a website with several React components. I've fetched the Google Maps API from one component and put it in a container in another component.

My problem is twofold:

1. That the map seems to go outside of the container in the sense that the 'hand' that you can use to drag the map appears out of bounds. [Hand appears outside of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd0bP.jpg) When I start dragging the map around I also see these strange blue lines appear as if the map actually exists in the whole window. [Blue lines when I drag map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqsQr.jpg)
2. That the icons for zoom control and street view move if I hover over them. They jump to another location in my window and don't come back. [Image showing how the icons appear far upper left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmIC4.jpg) My only solution has been to disable them in the map component and that's not a very  satisfying solution.

I've followed [a tutorial for how to make a grid layout](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-responsive-modern-dashboard-layout-with-css-grid-and-flexbox-bd343776a97e). I don't feel confident enough about my CSS to see whether it's this layout that's messing with the map so I've tried to include the relevant CSS under.

I've tried changing the position from 'relative' to 'absolute' to 'static'. And added !important in the CSS since the Google API seems to override it. This does not seem to influence these issues.

I've also spent a great deal of time on placing the map in the container it's in. The solution here was to make the map width: 100% and the height fixed (200px). This now occurs multiple places and is probably completely overkill:

```
CSS for the card that the hotel image, description and map appear in.

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;  
    background-color:rgba(44,182,187,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .card.map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      align-items: normal;
      padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    position: relative !important; 
    height: 200px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

```
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

class Map extends Component {
render() {
const style = {
    width: "100%",    
    height: 200,
    position: "relative",
 }

return (

    <Map 
        google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={13}
        mapTypeControl={false}
        // zoomControl={false}
        // streetViewControl={false}
        initialCenter={{
        lat: this.props.lat,
        lng: this.props.lng
        }}
        style={style}>
    <Marker position={{ lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng}} />
    </Map>
```

```
CSS that defines the grid layout:


.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "main";
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only managed to solve this by embedding the google map in the code.

I also used the props in the iframe component. Remember to activate the embedded API first in your developer profile at Google. I [followed this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) and found good help on Stackoverflow on how to include props.

[This is how it looks with the embedded map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi3nX.png)

So I didn't end up using a separate map component. I just put this text in where I imported the Map component previously:

```
<iframe 
     title= "greentravel"
     width="100%" 
     height="250px" 
     frameborder="0" 
     style={{ border: 0}}
     src={`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key= 
     0000000yourkey00000000&q=${props.lat},${props.lng}&zoom=15`} allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Without embedding I got the same problems in several browswers also using another API. Tried this one '@react-google-maps/api' also, but had the same problems as "google-maps-react".